# ¿Por qué un archivo al abrirlo con LiveServer muestra los cambios y sin LiverServe no

Tags: html

Esto es primera vez que me pasa, ya vi que es porque no esta en la misma carpeta, pero no entiendo el porque si en otros proyecto no me pasa

Comment: No estoy 100% seguro, pero creo que es porque el "server" llama y crea todas las rutas y dependencias, sin el server corriendo es solo un archivo con código que talvez no tenga los recursos necesarios para trabajar bien. Es como los archivos `PHP` sin Apache corriendo.

Comment: Pero mi duda es, porque en este proyecto sucede eso?, cuando colocos todos los archivos en una misma carpeta, funciona sin el live server, pero en otros proyecto no me habia pasado.